# office word add-in adfs login

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365, office-js, office-addins

I have login button that uses ADAL.js code, upon clicking the login button the Office Word  add-in redirects to ADFS login page with message **Taking you to your organization's sign-in page** , after entering the credentials on the ADFS page, the Wed Addin URL opens instead on new browser window and does not redirect back to the Office Add-in.

The office add-in login page does 
not get the details of the logon user , below is my code and screen shot

```
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);

        var isCallback = authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);
        authContext.handleWindowCallback();

        if (isCallback && !authContext.getLoginError()) {
            window.location = authContext._getItem(authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST);
        }

        var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
        if (!user) {
            authContext.login();
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkLXY.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the dialog api to solve this issue.

First, open the dialog to the adfs page using:

```
var dialog;
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(ADFS_URL_HERE, {height: 30, width: 20},
    function (asyncResult) {
        dialog = asyncResult.value;
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
    }
);
```

After it is open you can close it (or pass the user) once you get the user using:

```
Office.context.ui.messageParent({"type":"closeDialog"});
```

And the handler function:

```
function processMessage(arg) {
    var messageFromDialog = JSON.parse(arg.message);
    if(messageFromDialog.type == "closeDialog"){
        dialog.close();
    }
}
```

You can read more about the dialog api here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

Answer (score 0):

add "popUp: true" in your ADAL config so it will open a dialog and process there.